# Authenticate android app to call web api service

Tags: android, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, http-authentication

I have an android app that have a login form for student, and I want to check the student credential at web api depending on the stored data in sql server

I have searched the web and watch many videos that talking about many scenarios and nothing helped me.

All I want is a custom validation for my rest service (so I should send the credential for each request)

- What should I do at asp.net web api service
- how I can implement that at android application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used basic authentication for security,so I should provide the base64 encoding of

`username:password`

in header for each request as the following

authorization: Basic 'encoded username:password

```
  httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+encodeUsernameAndPassword());
```

At the server side I have implemented message handler

```
public class BasicAuthenticationHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        public readonly IAuthenticationService authService;
        public BasicAuthenticationHandler(IAuthenticationService service)
        {
            this.authService = service;
        }

        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            AuthenticationHeaderValue authHeader = request.Headers.Authorization;
            if (authHeader == null || authHeader.Scheme != "Basic")
            {
                return Unauthorized(request);
            }
            string encodedCredentials = authHeader.Parameter;
            var credentialsBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedCredentials);
            var credentials = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(credentialsBytes).Split(':');

            if (!authService.Authenticate(credentials[0], credentials[1]))
            {
                return Unauthorized(request);
            }

            string[] roles = null;//todo
            IIdentity identity = new GenericIdentity(credentials[0], "Basic");
            IPrincipal user = new GenericPrincipal(identity, roles);


            HttpContext.Current.User = user;


            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems you didn't search for "Web API Token Based Authentication" ;) Anyhow what you need to implement is very simple. 
You need to use OAuth 2.0 Resource Owner Credentials Flow which means that you want to provide the username/password only once for a specific endpoint i.e(/token) and then you if the username/password valid you obtain something called Bearer Access Token. 
This token is valid for specified period and you can configure this in your Web API.
Once you obtain the access token, you need to store it securely in your android app, then you keep sending it with each request to your web api protected end points using the Authorization header (Bearer scheme(.
I've written very detailed post which covers your scenario 100%. Please check the post [Token Based Authentication](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) and let me know if you need further help.